# Informatica Cloud: Can't connect to SQL Server (Receive timed out)

Tags: sql-server, informatica-cloud

I'm trying to create connection to SQL Server database from InformaticaCloud Administrator menu.

So far getting below error:

*The connection test failed because of the following error: [informatica][SQLServer JDBC Driver]The connection to the host COMPUTER, named instance COMPUTER has failed. Error: "Receive timed out". Verify the server and instance names, check that no firewall is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434, and for SQL Server 2005 or later verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host.*

Prerequisites I have now:

1) Firewall is disabled

2) Secure Agent installed and Runtime Environment assosiated with connection is up and running

3) Both host and instance name is Computer (select HOST_NAME(), @@servername)

4) SQL Server Browser is running

Could you please help to resolve described error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was managed to find  a solution:

1) leave Instance name field blank

2) use SQL Server Authentication instead of Windows one